# Sorting 2 single dimensional arrays into a 1 dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a code that chooses one by one from `a` and `b`. I want to make a 2 dimensional array where the first index is either `0 or 1`. `0` representing `a` and `1` representing `b` and the second index would just be the values in array `a` or `b` so it will be something like this `[[0 7][1 13]]`. I want the function to also have it in order so it will be The function starts off with `a` then it will be like `a,b,a,b,a...` if its the other way around `b,a,b,a,b...`. Comparing which index function comes before the other so since the first index of `b` is 0 and the first index of `a` is 7, since 0 < 7 the code will start off with b `[[1 0]]` and then it will go for the next index on 'a' which is `7` so the `[[1 0],[0, 7]]`. It will keep on doing this until it reaches the end of the array `a` and `b`. How can I get the expected output below?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([ 7,  9, 12, 15, 17, 22])
b = np.array([ 0, 13, 17, 18])
```

Expected Output:

```
[[ 1  0]
 [ 0  7]
 [ 1  13]
 [ 0  15]
 [ 1  17]
 [ 0  17]
 [ 1  18]
 [ 0  22]]
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.  We fix a problem in existing code; we do not write code from scratch: that’s your responsibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two arrays and sort the values while preserving the origin of each value (using 2N and 2N+1 offsetting).

Then filter out the consecutive odd/even values to only retain values with alternating origin indicator (1 or 0)

Finally, build the resulting array of [origin,value] pairs by reversing the 2N and 2N+1 tagging.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([ 7,  9, 12, 15, 17, 22])
b = np.array([ 0, 13, 17, 18])

p = 1 if a[0] > b[0] else 0 # determine first entry
c = np.sort(np.concatenate((a*2+p,b*2+1-p)))  # combine/sort tagged values
c = np.concatenate((c[:1],c[1:][c[:-1]%2 != c[1:]%2])) # filter out same-array repeats
c = np.concatenate(((c[:,None]+p)%2,c[:,None]//2),axis=1) # build result

print(c)
                
[[ 1  0]
 [ 0  7]
 [ 1 13]
 [ 0 15]
 [ 1 17]
 [ 0 17]
 [ 1 18]
 [ 0 22]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Numpy solution, but may work if you are okay processing these as lists. You can make iterators out of the lists, then alternate between them using `itertools.dropwhile` to proceed through the elements until you get the next in line. It might look something like:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

def pairs(a, b):
    index = 0 if a[0] <= b[0] else 1
    iters = [iter(a), iter(b)]   
    while True:
        try:
            current = next(iters[index])
            yield [index,current]
            index = int(not index)
        except StopIteration:
            break

        iters[index] = dropwhile(lambda n: n < current, iters[index])
        
list(pairs(a, b))
```

Which results in:

```
[[1, 0], [0, 7], [1, 13], [0, 15], [1, 17], [0, 17], [1, 18], [0, 22]]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use conditions of which array element is from -> with sorted values -> including condition of ->group wise split and ->flip

```
c = np.hstack([np.vstack([a, np.zeros(len(a))]), np.vstack([b, np.ones(len(b))])]).T
c = c[c[:, 0].argsort()]
# Group wise split and flip array - 2nd possiblity
d = np.vstack(np.apply_along_axis(np.flip, 0, np.split(c, np.unique(c[:,0], return_index = True)[1])))[::-1]

res1 = np.vstack([d[0], d[1:][d[:,1][:-1]!=d[:,1][1:]]])
res2 = np.vstack([c[0], c[1:][c[:,1][:-1]!=c[:,1][1:]]])
if res1.shape[0]>res2.shape[0]:
  print(res1)
else:
  print(res2)
```

Out:

```
[[ 0.  1.]
 [ 7.  0.]
 [13.  1.]
 [15.  0.]
 [17.  1.]
 [17.  0.]
 [18.  1.]
 [22.  0.]]
```